# Finding culprit method throwing 'undefined is not a function'

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, runtime-error

I am getting `TypeError : undefined is not a function` in Chrome Dev and a nice looking stack trace as follows.

```
"TypeError: undefined is not a function
at HTMLBodyElement.jQuery.event.dispatch (https://localhost/js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:5098:9)
at HTMLBodyElement.jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle (https://localhost/js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4768:46)
at Object.jQuery.event.trigger (https://localhost/js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:5010:12)
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (https://localhost/js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:5694:17)
at Function.jQuery.extend.each (https://localhost/js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:657:23)
at jQuery.fn.jQuery.each (https://localhost/js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:266:17)
at jQuery.fn.extend.trigger (https://localhost/js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:5693:15)
at HTMLTableSectionElement.eval (eval at evaluate (unknown source), <anonymous>:5:31)
at Function.jQuery.extend.each (https://localhost/js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:657:23)
at jQuery.fn.jQuery.each (https://localhost/js/lib/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js:266:17)"
```

I have tried putting console statements on relevant properties at the specified location in the stack trace but I get no clue as to what is triggering that.

**What am I trying to find?**

I am assuming that if I get this error that means a function which I am trying to access is not available in that context. It may be a typo as well. So I am trying to find the name of the function that is being accessed and causing the error to be thrown.

Any way to do that?

***THINKING...*** The JS engine must be knowing the *name of the method* that was going to be accessed and failed.

Comment: cool!, where is your code? I won't be able to find without code.

Comment: You are calling an method on undefined, mostly your jquery selector wont be returning any result. Can you put the code in :)

Comment: for policy stuff.. i cant put the code.(***super sad***) but it happens when I try to programmatically trigger click event on an element. `$(".selector").trigger("click")`;

Answer (score 2):

In your browser developer tools, there is an option to break on an exception.
For example in Chrome, press F12, switch to the "Sources" tab and find the "Pause" icon in the right subwindow.
That will make the script execution stop when the error occurs and you can inspect the current state/variables.

Comment: although that's not actually the answer I was looking for but it helped me in moving a step forward. I have found the culprit and it's some weird stuff with jquery `on` method when used with 3 arguments. where it is deliberately interpreting the second argument as handler when it should be the selector.